# How to use an InputMismatchException object

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I have an array of a specified sized created and must ask the user to enter an index and print that indexed value. However if they enter something that's not an int I need to use an `InputMismatchException` to check whether they've entered `'q'` or `'Q'` to terminate my program. My question is how do I do this. I have 
`catch (InputMismatchException ex)` and I've tried `if(ex == 'q'...)` but I'm not allowed to do this. In what way can I test the object?

EDIT: This is the code I have so far

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExceptionsWithUserInput {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int SIZE_OF_ARRAY = 100;
    final int MAX_OF_ARRAY = 10;
    final int MIN_OF_ARRAY = -10;
    float [] randomFloats = new float [SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){
        randomFloats [i] = (float) ((Math.random () * 10) - 10);
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Generating 100 random numbers in [-10.0,10.0) ...");
    boolean continueInput;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print ("Please enter an index: ");
            int index = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(
                    "The random number for index = " + index + " is "
                    + randomFloats[index]);
            continueInput = true;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
            System.out.println("ERROR: user-supplied index is out of bounds!");
            continueInput = true;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException ex){
            if (ex == 'q' )
            }
        }
    }
```

As I was saying I'm not sure how to use what the user inputs

Comment: I've added the code I have so far. I still haven't completed the do while loop since I"m stuck on this part.

Comment: If nextInt() is not an integer, then call next() to have the next token as a String, and test if this String equals "q". An exception is not a char. Comparing them makes no sense. Note that relying on exception for this is bad design. You should use hasNextInt() to test if the next token is an int.

Comment: Oh thank you. I understand what you mean. I just had to say if(input.next() == "q" in the catch block. I'm a student and a beginner at java so I'm sorry if this question seemed dumb.

Comment: Nizet meant, you should check with hasNextInt() so that this exception doesnt occur. You shouldn't use exceptions to check for something

Comment: @ShreeshamMukherjee you don't compare Strings with ==. That won't work. Use equals().

Comment: Oh right thanks just caught that and fixed it.

Comment: @Dude I understood what Nizet was saying but the purpose of this assignment was to handle errors so we had to do it this way.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (ex == 'q' ) is not true, you should check  input and write 
if (input == 'q')
```

Comment: I've tried that as well but I get an error saying scanner and char are incompatible

Comment: try this String.valueOf(input.nextLine().charAt(0))  == 'q'